# Email verifications for iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, email-validation

How can I check if the entered `email id` is valid or not ?

Like, I am getting code for verification for a@a.com

I tried this function.

```
- (BOOL)validateEmailWithString:(NSString*)email
{
    NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}"; 
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex]; 
    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:email];
}
```

But what if the user enters `a@a.com.com.com.com`

How can I verify that case? I'm happy for any suggestions.

Comment: For your regex itself try Start ->     ([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.!#\\$%&\\'\\*/=\\?\\^`{\\|}~\\+]+)@((\\[[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+\\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\\]?)     <- Finish

Answer (score 2):

You probably found that email address regex. This is a valid email address checker that includes subdomains for emails.

So your program can accept the valid email address `vrwim@dev.email.com`

If you want to change it to only accept non-subdomain email adresses (bad idea, my school uses them for all students), use `[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}`

Answer (score 0):

Coco function. check it

```
-(BOOL) NSStringIsValidEmail:(NSString *)checkString
{
   BOOL stricterFilter = NO;  
   NSString *stricterFilterString = @"[A-Z0-9a-z\\._%+-]+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
   NSString *laxString = @".+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2}[A-Za-z]*";
   NSString *emailRegex = stricterFilter ? stricterFilterString : laxString;
   NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
   return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:checkString];
}
```